# session id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and need to get current session id. I have used following code in controller.

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->library(array('session'));
}

public function index()
{
    $session_id=$this->session->userdata('session_id');

    $data['session_id']=$session_id;
    $this->load->view('cover',$data);
}
```

If I send print the `$session_id` in current page or sent it to cover view then it doesn't show the session id. Why it could be?

Answer (score 1):

As per https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

```
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
// or:
$name = $this->session->name
// or:
$name = $this->session->userdata('name');
```

You can also call it directly in your views `$this->session->session_id`

Comment: You can also use `session_id()`. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata

Answer (score 1):

First load library in your controller constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();  
$this->load->library('session');
}


public function index()
{
    $session_id=$this->session->session_id;

    $data['session_id']=$session_id;
    $this->load->view('cover',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Session Codeigniter v 3.11

```
$this->load->library('session');
$test = $this->session;
print_r($test->userdata);
```